# SVN Error Message

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am new to SVN and trying to add file in trunk.while adding file in trunk.
when i commit my folder.
it gives me this error message:
 commit failed(details below:)

1. MKActivity request on
   'svn/!svn/act/9361bac-725a-124f-8191-2c44f8571af5  failed: 405
   method not allowed
2. Additional errors: Delete request on
       'svn/!svn/act/93611bac-725a-124f-8191-2c44f8571af5' failed: 405
   method not allowed

kindly help!!
don't know how to resolve these errors.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please post in the commit command you're running - we need to know which protocol you're using (file, svn, svn+ssh, http)? Also please advise how your server is configured and which protocol that should be accepting?

Comment: using Svn tortoise for windows i used. and using https

Comment: In that case, unless there was an error in your command (we can't tell because you didn't give us the command you actually ran) it looks like your repository server isn't set up to accept commands via https. You could try http, though if that doesn't work you'll need to look at the server configuration.